# Can't find XP boot after Dual boot installation

Tags: 12.04, dual-boot, windows-xp

The machine in question is offline and I may have 'hatchet jobbed' the 12.04 installation.  Ubuntu seems fine so far (how would I know?) and the xp partition is verifiably intact.  Somewhere I have seen a warning that boot segments can be moved too 'deep' onto the hard drive to be seen.  If THIS is my problem, are they findable/relocatable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that the answer to my specific problem is found here:
http://ubuntuguide.org/wiki/Multiple_OS_Installation#Windows_bootloaders

If reboot to XP was so critical after a partition re-size, I'd have appreciated a warning a little earlier in my learning curve.  Maybe it could be added right after "be sure to back up your files."